# Name Standardizing - Removing Diacriticals

Tags: database, plsql, oracle11g

I have inherited a database that with a table of item_names.

The text in the item_names has non-standard text so a version of the name is created using a getStandardizedName PL/SQL function.  That version is used for search purposes (the same function is called against the search entered by an end user).

Within this function there are a lot of things like the code below.  My question is, isn't there a better way to do this?  This takes around 90 minutes for every million items.  Unfortunately, the current workflow requires this to be done 5 - 6 times per week.

Note that there are more than 80 of the following type of 'REPLACE'

```
   l_name := REPLACE(l_name, 'STE-', ' SAINT ');
   l_name := REPLACE(l_name, 'ST-', ' SAINT ');

   l_name := replace(l_name, '+','');
   l_name := replace(l_name, '-','');

   l_name := replace(l_name, '=','');
   l_name := replace(l_name, '_','');
   l_name := replace(l_name, '.','');
```

Comment: Found a partial solution for punctuation as follows:  
      l_name := REGEXP_REPLACE(l_name,  '([[:punct:]])', ' ')

Answer (score 0):

If you can identify common patterns/groupings you should be able to replace them all with a couple of [regexp_replace](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions137.htm) calls. You have already identified the punctuation example in your comment.

```
l_name := regexp_replace(l_name, '([[:punct:]])', ' ')
```

The SAINT pair could be replaced with:

```
l_name := regexp_replace(l_name, 'ST[E]{0,1}-', 'SAINT ')
```